# How to call Custom Workflow Activity inside another Custom Workflow Activity

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I have a Custom Workflow Activity (A) that does a certain validation a returns a boolean value depending on the result; I want to do the same validation inside another Custom Workflow Activity (B) and, since I'd like to avoid repeating code, I wonder if there is a way for me to call Custom Workflow Activity A inside the code of Custom Workflow Activity B.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new `Action` and this action needs to have a step that performs the `Workflow Activity B`, then you can call this action in your `Workflow Activity A` by using `OrganizationRequest`.